# Is "as easy as eating candy" idiomatic or common used in spoken English?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

When translating it from Vietnamese (my mother tongue) to English, it is "**it's as easy as eating candy**". That is a common expression in Vietnamese.

I couldn't find this phrase "**as easy as eating candy**" in any English dictionary.

Interestingly, I see about 15 phrases containing it [from Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20easy%20as%20eating%20candy%22&sca_esv=da56b67854fd2398&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn0_0ekrTq4pQkhSNOl870bXpLoiZzg:1710397827942&ei=g5nyZZL6OMTO2roPyJGDqAM&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjSx9W3kPOEAxVEp1YBHcjIADUQ8tMDegQIDhAE&biw=1203&bih=592&dpr=1.54)

Is "**as easy as eating candy**" idiomatic or common used in spoken English?

If not, do you have a similar phrase?

I know children often say "**easy-peasy**".

Comment: Not common in my experience (older male UK native speaker). The word 'candy' is mainly used in American English (Brits mostly say 'sweets'). If something is very easy we may say it is as easy as 'taking candy (or sweets) from a baby'. Another idiomatic expression is 'as easy as falling off a log'.

Comment: A lot of adults will also say "easy-peasy". Sometimes it's even extended to "easy peasy lemon squeezy" for extra fun and emphasis.

Comment: Somewhat related would be calling something a "cake walk", meaning it's a simple thing to accomplish:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/459926/why-is-the-phrase-cake-walk-informally-used-to-describe-an-easy-to-achieve-tas

Comment: The most common idiom is: easy as pie

Comment: Careful with google finds in general (seems not to apply to the books but for example to some videos showing up): Some are from non-native speakers who simply use their native idioms in English! (Of course, these idioms may over time become part of the "official" English...)

Comment: I was going to try to write up an answer of idioms that are similar in meaning but not similar in phrasing but all I could come up with at the moment was "Like a hot knife through butter"

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I don't think they become part of ''official'' English.  They become part of certain dialects, like the influence of immigrant speech on dialects from London (''it's a madness'').

Comment: I'm with Michael, every word. Meanwhile, if Google Books gave you 15 passages containing the phrase isn't it fairly clear the phrase is acceptable, or it's out-dated, or Google is simply wrong?

Comment: What does it mean? I'm inferring that it means something is easy, but idioms aren't necessarily literal, for example "easy as pie" means something is easy (and that might be exactly what you're looking for), but pie's actually pretty hard to make :p

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No.  There are several similar sounding idioms:  "It's as easy as pie", or "It's a piece of cake"  both of which allude to the ease of eating sweet soft food  (but never "It's as easy as cake" or "a piece of pie")

There is also the simile "like taking candy from a baby".

As with many of these sayings, they are cliché and more skilled native speakers will try to avoid them.

Comment: Even native speakers with very good vocabulary use clichés.

Comment: Skilled native speakers avoid them *when they want to sound skilled*, like in a work presentation. In just casual conversation clichés can still be pretty common

Comment: I'll add that "like taking candy from a baby" is usually only used to refer to the ease of taking advantage of someone. You wouldn't say "this test was like taking candy from a baby". You would say "this test was a piece of cake". But if a mechanic successfully ripped off a customer, they might say it was like taking candy from a baby

Comment: @THummus I just have to say I wish I could where you work where people *avoid* cliches in presentations. Where I’ve worked cliches seem make up about 80% of all communication.

Comment: @ToddWilcox yeah, work presentation was a bad example (clichés abound at my work as well). Although the clichés I hear at work are usually unique to "business speak". I don't think I would hear someone say "easy as pie" in a work presentation

Comment: @ToddWilcox "Business speak" is often overused and misused but such cliches can be useful.  For example, I've seen a lot of people complain about "it is what it is" as being meaningless but I think they are missing the point.  It's really just a quick and relatively non-confrontational way to say "Please stop talking about the thing(s) we have no power to change"

Comment: @ToddWilcox - when I worked for the British Civil Service, we used to play 'meeting bingo'. The idea is to have a list of management-speak clichés and every time an important speakers uses one, to cross it out. From memory: drill down, deep dive, quick win, low hanging fruit, unpack, low hanging fruit, optics, not a good look, re-invent the wheel...

Comment: @JimmyJames - or a way of shutting down people who want to change something that actually is possible to change, in my experience, or of performatively establishing status.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey And that's the 'misuse' that's also common. The problem isn't the phrase, it's the misuse.  If someone tells me "I'm the most honest person ever" when they lie through their teeth on an almost constant basis, I don't go on a rage about how the phrase "most honest person ever" is bad.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "Low hanging fruit" is a good one.  As a child, I used to help out my on grandparents (small) orchard.  I remember climbing up the cherry trees to get the fruit that wasn't "low-hanging".  For me at least, it's a really clear idiom for "things of value that are easily achieved"

Comment: From the examples in Google Books, it looks like the phrase had some popularity in the late 19th/early 20th century but you wouldn't usually hear it today - there are a couple of examples from more recent foreign authors who may not have English as their first language. I agree with the other posters that there are many better phrases.

Comment: Cliches are endemic in the business world. Especially sports metaphors. 'Hail Mary pass', 'swing for the fences', 'drop the ball', 'home run', 'get over your skis', (in Canada anyway) 'stick handled', etc. But I guess that's just par for the course.

Answer (score 0):

As James says, we don't have that idiom. Another similar one that hasn't been mentioned yet is "as easy as shelling peas". See [thefreedictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/(as)+easy+as+shelling+peas) for a reference.

Comment: Never heard that one and I've shelled my share of peas.

Comment: I have never heard that.

Answer (score 0):

Another equivalent idiom: [child's play](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/child-s-play). "Something that is very easy to do" (Cambridge Dictionary).